# jnice plugin combobox

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have used jnice plugin for combobox,
suppose one of the value in combobox is jordan,so when i type 'j',i should automatically go to jordan,like normal combobox,but its not working with jnice plugin

Answer (score 0):

I went to their demo [site](http://www.whitespace-creative.com/jquery/jNice/) and tried it (chrome). Its not working on demo too. I think it will not support that functionality.